# Why am I getting empty result whenI apply a condition to skip array value whose key is even number?

Tags: javascript

Am trying to print an array value at random which worked fine. but when I apply a condition to skip array whose keys are odd (not even) I sometimes get a result that displays nothing, dunno why. please need help.

Here is the code:

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
if(rand % 2 !== 0)
  console.log(arr[rand]);
```

Comment: The `console.log` message prints conditionally, i.e. when `rand % 2 !== 0`, and it is as per your logic. What else did you expect?

Comment: If the result shows nothing means the rand is even. Case close.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array has 6 elements, Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) gives you a number between 0 and 5.

Then you check if that number is even by using modulo.
So in half of the cases, you won't log anything to the console, because the random number is 2, 4, 6 ...

`if(rand % 2 !== 0) {
  console.log(arr[rand]);
}`

basically says: print the rand'th number from the array if rand is not even.

Answer (score 0):

Using `if...else` without curly braces will consider next immediate line as conditional.

```js
if (true) 
    console.log("in if")
else
    console.log("in else")
```

So, in your case when your `if` condition not met, it will not print your `console.log`

**One more example:**

```js
if (false) 
        console.log("in if...1")
        console.log("in if...2")
```

`in if...2` will always print because it is now not a part of if condition. because it is separated by `new line (\n)`

> **Note:-** If condition without braces considers a next immediate line as conditional. after `\n` it will not look further.

So, if you apply space between two consoles instead enter then it will be still part of `if` condition:

```js
if (true) 
            console.log("in if...1");                                           console.log("in if...2");
```